# How can I disable multiwindow mode for an Activity in Android N+

Tags: android, multi-window, android-n-preview

In the developer preview for Android N, multi-window support is enabled by default.  How can I disable it for activites?  Also what will happen if a multi-window enabled app launches my disabled activity?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

In your manifest, you need:

```
android:resizeableActivity="false"
```

So in your manifest file, for each activity that you want to disable the feature in, it would be like:

```
<activity android:name=".SomeActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:resizeableActivity="false" />
```

Or, if you want to disable it in your entire app:

```
<application 
   android:resizeableActivity="false" >
    . . .
</application>
```

As for what will happen, Android just won't let your app go into multi-screen mode - it will just stay full screen. See https://developer.android.com/preview/features/multi-window.html and https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#resizeableActivity.

Comment: For apps targeting Android N, setting this flag just gives a message that "App may not work in split mode" . But the app still goes to the split screen mode.

Comment: @Diffy this could be only possible if you enabled force multi window support from Developers options.

Comment: android:resizeableActivity="true" breaks the overall app design then how do i support split screen (app layout responsive design) in android nougat

Comment: don't forget to change your targetSdkVersion over 24 for "android:resizeableActivity" working

Comment: @Diffy did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: While starting a Unresizable Activity You should also add `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag to Intent.Otherwise it will inherit the properties from the root activity.

Add `android:resizeableActivity="false"` for your Activity in your Manifest file or you can also add this for your Application:

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:resizeableActivity="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

By the way, I added `android:resizeableActivity="false"` to Manifest and then I switched language with Locale some Activities didn't change language. I noticed some activities have different resources. When I remove resizebleActivity property in Manifest it works OK.